# python 3.5.0 ::: Int() attributes

Tags: python, attributes, int, python-3.5

Can anyone help studying these attributes that belong to the `int()` function:
Example : When you call a variable and add an attribute thats in the directory of the `int()` function:

```
a = 5
print (a.bit_length())
```

> 2

What does the bit_length() atribute do to the variable? And I want to know the rest of them

- bit_length
- conjugate
- denominator
- from_bytes
- imag
- numerator
- real
- to_bytes

I don't understand their use. Can you give me some examples?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Can you please add additional details to clarify what exactly you're asking about and what you're looking for?

Comment: have you look at [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/numbers.html#) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) and [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#additional-methods-on-integer-types)

Comment: @RNar can you explain me what does the -0b stands for in the example showing the binary number of -37?
I'm working with python 3.5.0, the first two this does not work with me. Thanks

Comment: if you change the `/2/` in those links to `/3/`, they will show the docs for python 3. `0b` is just another way to declare an `int` in python, ie type in `0b0010` into your interpreter and it will read it as "oh, he wants the decimal value for the binary `0010` (which is 2)"

Comment: @RNar Iread the python 3.5.0 subject int, but it doesn't say anything about this attributes, only talks about bit_length one

Comment: @InêsBarataFeioBorges you have to look into python [`Numbers'](https://docs.python.org/3/library/numbers.html#). most of those methods have to do with the fact that python allows for complex numbers (numbers with imaginary parts like 5+6j or something)

Comment: @RNar that part explains the complex numbers but it doesn't use the int() function

Comment: none of them use the "int() function", they are all methods/attributes for the `int` type, which is a base class under the `Numbers` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bit_length ---> Returns the number of bits necessary to represent an integer in binary, excluding the sign and leading zeros.

Have a look at http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/ints/bit_length.html

Answer (score 0):

The `bit_length` function returns the number of bits needed to represent the integer in binary.

The `conjugate` method and `real` property store are no-ops which are present to allow code that expects complex numbers to work with integers (by treating them as having a zero imaginary part). The `imag`property is always zero for the same reason.

The `numerator` property always is equal to the number itself and exists to allow code that expects fractions (from the `fractions` module) to work with numbers. The `denominator` property is always one for the same reason.